# Is there a way to easily pass a JSON object to Django context for Chart.js?

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I want to use Chart.js as the plotting tool and write a Django view that will run an ORM query, get some data, turn it into JSON, pass the JSON data to the Django context, and render the plot in the Django template without too much fuss. I am hoping to do this as simply as possible.

I was able to do something like this with Highcharts-django but it is prohibitively expensive.

This is roughly what I'd like to do:

**(1) Get data loaded in 'get_context_data' via an ORM query in views.py and format the data into json using 'local_utils.py' method `generate_chart(data)`**

```
from local_utils import generate_chart

class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "template.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_source = MyModel.objects.fitler(start_date__gte=start_date).values()
        my_chart = generate_chart(data_source)
        context['my_chart'] = my_chart
```

**(2) Pass the data to the method `generate_chart(data_source)` and return a LineChartJSONView object (or something)**

```
from random import randint
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from chartjs.views.lines import BaseLineChartView

def generate_chart(data_source):
    class LineChartJSONView(BaseLineChartView):
        def get_labels(self):
            """Return labels for the x-axis."""
            return data_source.values_list('x-data', flat=True)

        def get_providers(self):
            """Return names of datasets."""
            return ['data']

        def get_data(self):
            """Return datasets to plot on y-axis."""
            return data_source.values_list('y-data', flat=True)

    line_chart = TemplateView.as_view(template_name='line_chart.html')
    line_chart_json = LineChartJSONView.as_view()

    return line_chart_json
```

**(3) Pass the context object `my_chart` to template.html**

```
<head>
    {{ my_chart|load_data_to:"container" }}
</head>
<body>
    {# Other stuff #}
    {% if chart %}
        <div id='container'>Chart will go here</div>
    {% endif %}
    {# Other stuff #}
</body>
```

**(4) Plot something like this: https://github.com/peopledoc/django-chartjs#3-get-a-chartjs-line-chart**

I have seen [the usage in the docs](https://github.com/peopledoc/django-chartjs) where the only thing happening in a View is the plotting. However, I'd like to have the plot embedded within a TemplateView. Is this possible with Chart.js? If yes, how?

Comment: How frequent do you need the data to refresh? If it's frequently, yu could use the django rest framework to serialize the data, present it as json, and point your javascript script to it (like I did here - https://github.com/ronaldgreeff/django-chartjs/tree/master/django_charts/charts